# How to stress test a telnet server application?

Tags: telnet, stress-testing

We have a Unix application that is essentially a glorified telnet server.
We have no access to the Unix server, yet we need to do load/stress testing.

We really need to be able to simulate a few hundred user sessions logging in and performing certain actions.
I thought I could perhaps use a terminal emulator that performs these actions concurrently.
But I am unsure of the best way to do this.

Is there any software that exists that would allow me to do this?
Or could someone recommend as easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I was going to do something like this I'd use a multithreaded perl program built around [Net::Telnet](http://search.cpan.org/~jrogers/Net-Telnet-3.03/lib/Net/Telnet.pm), maybe using [Expect](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.21/) and [Benchmark](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.2/lib/Benchmark.pm) depending on your objectives.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for https://github.com/ztellman/aleph/wiki/TCP